# "Народный герой России". Герой - со строчной или прописной?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Как правильно написать: "Народный герой России" или "Народный Герой России"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильное написание: **"Народный герой России"**, если это название премии, конкурса. Например, существует  региональная (г. Омск)  премия **"Народный герой"** , которая присуждается ежегодно голосованием  ("Народный герой - 2016").

Написание **с прописной буквы:** **Герой Российской Федерации** (неофиц. **Герой России**) —  высшее звание, присваиваемое за заслуги перед государством и народом, связанные с совершением геройского подвига.